# How do I iterate over a MULTI_SZ string in Inno Setup?

Tags: scripting, inno-setup, pascal

How do I iterate over a MULTI_SZ string in Inno Setup Pascal scripting?
e.g. over values returned by `RegQueryMultiStringValue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code to do it:

```
var
  I,StartPos:Integer;
  MultiSzStr,Element:String;

...

  StartPos := 1;
  for I:= 1 to Length(MultiSzStr) do
  begin
    if MultiSzStr[I] = #0 then
    begin
      Element := Copy(MultiSzStr, StartPos, I - StartPos);
      { do something with the element }
      StartPos := I + 1;
    end;
  end;
```